# How can a .bat file start bash and change directory?

Tags: windows-10, batch-file

I was using

```
start bash
cd "/mnt/c/Users/James/Documents/_Github-Projects"
```

but this doesn't make any sense since `start bash` will open a new window, but the `cd` command is still ran on the other window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized shortly after, the bash window opened automatically cd's into the directory the other cmd prompt was in. So I have this is my .bat file

```
cd "C:/Users/James/Documents/_Github-Projects"
start bash
```